# How to compile a windows 10 visual studio 2015 project for windows 7 users

Tags: frameworks

I am trying to make executable for windows 7 users, but I am using visual studios 2015 on windows 10 and I cant make it work. I tried to install the windows 7 SDK with NET Framework 4, but I couldnt install the compiler ( it said "you need to install NET Framework 4 first") . So I uninstalled all NET Frameworks and I trief to install NET Framework 4 manually, but this didn't work either ( it said "a later Framework is already installed) . So I suggest that windows 10 has 4.6 integrated and now I don't know what to do , please help me! :D

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the SDK for Windows 7 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=3138).

The installation process on Windows 10 should automatically recognize that you do not have .NET 3.5 installed and it will require you to install it, follow the instructions as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh506443(v=vs.120).aspx).

Once you have the the SDK installed you have to configure the VS project to compile using it (and not the default windows 10 SDK) as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764(v=vs.100).aspx).

Install Visual Studio 2012 and use its toolset which will enable your program to link against msvcrt110.dll and run out of the box on Windows 7.

Set The toolset by `right clicking your project -> properties -> General -> Platfrom Toolset -> Visual Studio 2012 (v110)`